# Get frames from RTSP stream using GStreamer 1.0 in C++

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to get rtsp video frames using GStreamer 1.0 and Qt libs. I have problem with getting frames form **appsink**, because somehow my callback function does not work.

```
FrameFlow::FrameFlow()
{
    pipeline_ = gst_parse_launch ("rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:rce@192.168.88.240:554 ! decodebin ! appsink name=sink", nullptr);
    sink_ = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline_), "sink");
    gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals(GST_APP_SINK(sink_), TRUE);
    g_signal_connect(sink_, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(newSample(GST_APP_SINK(sink_), (gpointer) this)), (gpointer)this);

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline_, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}

GstFlowReturn FrameFlow::newSample(GstAppSink *sink, gpointer gSelf)
{
    GstSample* sample = NULL;
    GstMapInfo bufferInfo;

    FrameFlow* self = static_cast<FrameFlow* >(gSelf);
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(sink_));
    if(sample != NULL)
    {
        buffer_ = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
        if(buffer_ != NULL)
        {
            gst_buffer_map(buffer_, &bufferInfo, GST_MAP_READ);
            self->mutex_.lock();
            self->image_ = QImage(bufferInfo.data, 320, 180, QImage::Format_RGB888);
            self->mutex_.unlock();
            gst_buffer_unmap(buffer_, &bufferInfo);
        }
        gst_sample_unref(sample);
    }
    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}
```

I am trying to register `newSample()` function as callback, but when I to debug that function, it's not called even once, but memory is leaking (i guess it works, because when I comment `gst_element_set_state(pipeline_, GST_STATE_PLAYING);`, it doesn't leak anymore).

Where am I doing mistake?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't this just be `g_signal_connect(sink_, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(newSample), (gpointer)this);`? Also you could try to set `emit-signals=true` in the pipeline description itself. P.S. You will need a proper GMainloop to make this work - do you have one?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Yes, `G_CALLBACK` was problem, I wasn't using static method, that's why it didn't work. Thanks for your help